# Tidymodels - How to correctly use verbose = TRUE in control = control_grid

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am trying to use verbose = TRUE to see the progress of the tuning grid.
It does not seem to work for me, do I have it in the wrong spot or am I using it incorrectly? At the bottom is a screenshot of what I want and below is reproducible code that does not have the desired output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
options(tidymodels.dark = TRUE)

parks <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-06-22/parks.csv')

modeling_df <- parks %>% 
  select(pct_near_park_data, spend_per_resident_data, med_park_size_data) %>% 
  rename(nearness = "pct_near_park_data",
         spending = "spend_per_resident_data",
         acres = "med_park_size_data") %>% 
  mutate(nearness = (parse_number(nearness)/100)) %>% 
  mutate(spending = parse_number(spending))

set.seed(123)
park_split <- initial_split(modeling_df)
park_train <- training(park_split)
park_test <- testing(park_split)

tree_rec <- recipe(nearness ~., data = park_train)
tree_prep <- prep(tree_rec)
juiced <- juice(tree_prep)

tune_spec <- rand_forest(
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = 1000,
  min_n = tune()
) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("ranger")

tune_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(tree_rec) %>% 
  add_model(tune_spec)

set.seed(234)
park_folds <- vfold_cv(park_train)

set.seed(345)
tune_res <- tune_grid(
  tune_wf,
  resamples = park_folds,
  grid = 20,
 control = control_grid(verbose = TRUE)
)

# Results of running the code
> tune_res <- tune_grid(
+   tune_wf,
+   resamples = park_folds,
+   grid = 20,
+   control = control_grid(verbose = TRUE)
+ )
i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
```

Here is an example of what I want it to look like
[image: Example of what I want]

Comment: Apart from you specific problem, I found that you can use `options(tune.dark = TRUE)` to print the message in easier to see colors.  https://github.com/tidymodels/tune/pull/109

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) to make your examples to ensure that you are running this in a fresh session and there are no other packages loaded that may be interfering with your options?

This is what I get with your example code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
options(tidymodels.dark = TRUE)

parks <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-06-22/parks.csv')
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_double(),
#>   city = col_character(),
#>   park_pct_city_data = col_character(),
#>   pct_near_park_data = col_character(),
#>   spend_per_resident_data = col_character(),
#>   city_dup = col_character()
#> )
#> ℹ Use `spec()` for the full column specifications.

modeling_df <- parks %>% 
   select(pct_near_park_data, spend_per_resident_data, med_park_size_data) %>% 
   rename(nearness = "pct_near_park_data",
          spending = "spend_per_resident_data",
          acres = "med_park_size_data") %>% 
   mutate(nearness = (parse_number(nearness)/100)) %>% 
   mutate(spending = parse_number(spending))

set.seed(123)
park_split <- initial_split(modeling_df)
park_train <- training(park_split)
park_test <- testing(park_split)

tree_rec <- recipe(nearness ~., data = park_train)
tree_prep <- prep(tree_rec)
juiced <- juice(tree_prep)

tune_spec <- rand_forest(
   mtry = tune(),
   trees = 1000,
   min_n = tune()
) %>% 
   set_mode("regression") %>% 
   set_engine("ranger")

tune_wf <- workflow() %>% 
   add_recipe(tree_rec) %>% 
   add_model(tune_spec)

set.seed(234)
park_folds <- vfold_cv(park_train, v = 5)

set.seed(345)
tune_res <- tune_grid(
   tune_wf,
   resamples = park_folds,
   grid = 20,
   control = control_grid(verbose = TRUE)
)
#> i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> i Fold1: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> i Fold2: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> i Fold3: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> i Fold4: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20
#> i Fold5: preprocessor 1/1, model 20/20 (predictions)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I do see the verbose output.

I suspect that you may have turned on parallel processing at some point, which turns **off** the ability to return verbose logging. It's not currently possible to collect logging from the workers with the parallel backends we support.